# Samsung Galaxy 2.3.5 usb storage broken

Tags: usb

My Samsung Galaxy 2.3.5 is showing the tool bar message *'USB storage broken'* .

I'm unable to enter the gallery, photos or videos. I have no SD Card in the phone, all all the storage I have is internal phone storage. The phone is not connecting to the computer, how can I get the photos back?

I've already switched it on and off, took out battery and connected it to my laptop but these haven't worked.

Comment: Which Galaxy? S? mini?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the sdcard is corrupted so other than trying to use a data recovery tool via USB from your PC to your phone to recover it it looks like you will have to either

1) format the sdcard storage via the settings

or

2) do a factory reset

Both resulting in losing all the data on the sdcard, sorry :'(